# Question about <uri> on Fortress

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I've decided to try and create a blanket for ignition just to practice on my skill. So I came up with an idea by import a piece of blanket over and over.

So, I wanted to try one piece only.

This is a [piece of blanket](https://github.com/Kakcalu13/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/blob/main/model/blanket.sdf) which is ready to be imported by another file.

So, I created a [different file](https://github.com/Kakcalu13/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/blob/main/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf) just to import a piece of blanket.

This section doesn't allow me to import due to no file found:

```
    <include>
        <static>false</static>
        <name>piece_00</name>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <uri>blanket.sdf</uri>
    </include>
```

But I have the blanket.sdf in the same folder as this file.

So the error output is this:

```
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L44]: Msg: Unable to find uri[model://blanket.sdf]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L44]: Msg: Unable to find uri[blanket.sdf]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L44]: Msg: Unable to find uri[blanket]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L44]: Msg: Unable to find uri[model://blanket.sdf]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L84]: Msg: Unable to find uri[model://blanket.sdf]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L84]: Msg: Unable to find uri[model://blanket]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L84]: Msg: Unable to find uri[blanket]
bwuk@robots:~/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket$ ign gazebo -r model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf 
[Err] [Server.cc:183] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="testing_physics"]/include[0]/uri:/home/bwuk/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket/model/blanket_in_a_world.sdf:L84]: Msg: Unable to find uri[blanket.sdf]
```

As you can see I tried all different ways.

What is the right way to import a model from other file?

Version: Fortress. (I'm addicted with this one!)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27739/question-about-%3Curi%3E-on-fortress/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Found a way to import a model from other model.

There was a lot of errors that prevented it from import other file.

First of all, in `blanket.sdf`

1. It had  `<pose relative_to='world'>` in the sdf file when there is no world model in it.
2. I removed  since blanket.sdf is designed to be a model only without anything else.
3. I learned that you need to `set  SDF_PATH and IGN_FILE_PATH`. It's explained in [here](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/sdf_worlds#download-the-model)

As for the blanket_in_the_world.sdf,
you need to give it a right path. So here is what I did:

```
<include>
  <uri>model://blanket.sdf</uri>
</include>
```

Just like that. I did this in Fortress only.

Feel free to ask me to clarify. I'm more than happy to clarify for you in future. (even if this is closed or marked as answer)

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-01-16**:
P.S., this will be [on my github](https://github.com/Kakcalu13/Ignition-Gazebo-blanket).